# Safe Point Thinning Algorithm - How to?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, algorithms, opencv

I am relatively new to image processing and am working on a project that requires the thinning of binary images. In the literature, I've seen references to the Safe Point Thinning Algorithm(SPTA) quite a lot, but have failed to find any definitive source to the algorithm, maybe because most of the articles quoted to describe the SPTA are not in the public domain. **Can you please explain SPTA for me? Or even point me to (free)resources that do?** The pros and cons of the algorithm are welcome. I could also use any alternative algorithm that is "good enough".

Comment: What references have you seen?

Comment: For example, in papers related to unconstrained handwritten character recognition by Hanmandlu et al.

Answer (score 4):

SPTA seems to be a quite old skeleton algorithm that is even hard to find behind paywalls. 
Here is a link to a skeletonization paper that references it and comes with free access : http://dspace1.acs.ucalgary.ca/bitstream/1880/45551/2/1987-287-35.pdf

But roughly speaking the idea of skeleton algorithms is to look of a simple shape "midway" inside the detected blob. For example, if you have detected a rectangle, then its skeleton is going to be the points inside the rectangle that are at equal distance from its boundaries, which makes a shape like this (the part inside the rectangle):

```
--------
|>----<|
--------
```

If it helps, think of the way children draw characters wit just a few strokes...

**-- EDIT --**

OK, if I had to choose some reference to implement (but I understood from the question that SPTA was actually used, not to be replaced), I would check the papers on this page:
http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~manzaner/publis.html

Disclaimer: I'm not this guy, I didn't write the papers, but I would start here because:

1. the papers are available for download
2. A. Manzanera worked a lot on limited hardware (e.g. embedded stuff), so I guess the algorithms are efficient and not so tricky to implement

Comment: So what algorithm do you suggest that is more modern and efficient than the SPTA to thin handwritten scribbles/signatures?

Comment: OK, I added a link to papers. Please read carefully the disclaimer to understand why this one page.